# Select the 2nd to latest record for each User ID in a table in Sqlite

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I have a table like below from which I want to get the 2nd from latest based on mtg_date.

```
  id_pk      user_id        mtg_date
+------ |------------|--------------------+
|   0   | LastFirst  | 2019-01-02 1:00:00 |
|   1   | LastFirst  | 2020-01-02 1:00:00 |
|   2   | LastFirst  | 2020-01-03 1:00:00 |
|   3   | LastFirst  | 2020-01-04 1:00:00 |
|   4   | JonesBob   | 2020-02-02 1:00:00 |
|   5   | JonesBob   | 2020-03-02 1:00:00 |
|   6   | JonesBob   | 2020-04-02 1:00:00 |
|   7   | JonesTom   | 2020-07-02 1:00:00 |
|   8   | JonesTom   | 2020-07-03 1:00:00 |
|   9   | JonesTom   | 2020-09-02 1:00:00 |
+------ |------------|--------------------+
```

What I want to get:

```
  id_pk      user_id        mtg_date
+------ |------------|--------------------+
|   2   | LastFirst  | 2020-01-03 1:00:00 |
|   5   | JonesBob   | 2020-03-02 1:00:00 |
|   8   | JonesTom   | 2020-07-03 1:00:00 |
+------ |------------|--------------------+
```

Records are NOT sorted by user_or or mtg_date, but added when the next meeting date is scheduled.

I found this on another question but don't entirely understand it, and it is not working for me. Also, I am doing this in Python3 with Sqlite3.

```
            SELECT id_pk, user_id, Meeting_Date
            FROM Meetings
                    WHERE Meeting_Date IN (SELECT Meeting_Date
                    FROM Meetings AS T2
                    WHERE T2.id_pk = Meetings.id_pk
                    ORDER BY Meeting_Date DESC
                    LIMIT 3 OFFSET 1)        
                    """)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` window function.

> I want to get the 2nd from latest based on mtg_date

So if the date defines the order then use it like this:

```
select id_pk, user_id, mtg_date
from (
  select *, row_number() over (partition by user_id order by mtg_date desc, id_pk desc) rn
  from Meetings
)
where rn = 2;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/g5LmDLq2HUrntpkVZEUVyi/1).
Results:

```
| id_pk | user_id   | mtg_date           |
| ----- | --------- | ------------------ |
| 2     | LastFirst | 2020-01-03 1:00:00 |
| 5     | JonesBob  | 2020-03-02 1:00:00 |
| 8     | JonesTom  | 2020-07-03 1:00:00 |
```

Comment: This worked great if I run it in DB Browser for SQLite, but anytime I try in  Python I get an error. When I added it as a view, every query in Python gives a similar error but it it all works fine in 
DB Browser for SQLite

```
malformed database schema (Mtg_View) - near "(": syntax error
```

Comment: Window functions are supported in SQLite since version 3.25.0 So it seems that Python uses an older version.